# Linking 'muted speaker' icon to volume slider when value = 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I have a speaker icon besides my volume slider, and I would like the icon to change when the volume value is at 0, to a second (muted) speaker icon. I've tried different variations which didn't work. How do I do that? Thanks!

```js
var volumeslider;
volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
 // Add Event Handling
 volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", setvolume);
 // Functions
 function setvolume(){
     audio.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
    }
```

```css
input[type=range] {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 60%;
 margin: 10px 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
 outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 animate: 0.2s;
 background: #000000;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 height: 20px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 background: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 background: #666666;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 animate: 0.2s;
 background: #000000;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 height: 20px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 background: #666666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 animate: 0.2s;
 background: transparent;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-width: 16px 0;
 color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
 background: #2a6495;
 border: 0.2px solid #010101;
 border-radius: 2.6px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
 background: #3071a9;
 border: 0.2px solid #010101;
 border-radius: 2.6px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 height: 20px;
 width: 10px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 background: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
 background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
 background: #367ebd;
}
```

```html
    <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
    <img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Android/PNG/48/Mobile/speaker-48.png" width="25" height="32">
```

Comment: So set the src when the value is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQs attr method to just swap the image source. Also, make sure the src path to the images is relative to the HTML document if you are using an external JS document.

**JS:**

```
 volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", checkMute);
```

//check for mute each time the slider is dragged.

```
function checkMute(){
    if (audio.volume == 0){
        $( ".speaker" ).attr("src", "images/speaker.png");
    }else{
        $( ".speaker" ).attr("src", "images/speakermute.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't get it to work.<img class=".speaker" src="images/speaker.png" width="25" height="32">
<script>
if (audio.volume == 0){
    $(".speaker").attr("src", "images/speakermuted.png");
}else{
    $(".speaker").attr("src", "images/speaker.png");
}
</script>

Comment: it won't let me edit or properly structure the above reply. what am i doing wrong? there isn't supposed to be a . before "speaker" in the image class.

Comment: Depends on how you structured your CSS. If you are appending the icon using the :before pseudoclass, then you will have to modify the target object in $( ".your-volume-icon-class" ) to target the icon class (or if it is appended to an object using the :before pseudoclass, you will want to include yourobjectname::before

All the code above does is grab the icon from the DOM and converts it to a jQuery object so you can manipulate it - and then swaps out the attribute "src" path to point at the mute icon when volume is 0.

Also, that is the handler. You need a watcher. Ill edit the code.