# Display mute icon on Android TV

Tags: android-tv

Android Version O
Is there any way to display mute icon when volume level is 0?
I thought it is possible using SystemUi but I was not able to find any point.

Comment: Try the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966830/linking-muted-speaker-icon-to-volume-slider-when-value-0), if this is the function you need. Also as an addition, you can try [this video.js from github](https://github.com/videojs/video.js). I think this is related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I want to know Android not js.